# Web Storage API Session Storage: delete all keys like XYZ

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

Given the following HTML session data:

```
hasSession                            1
user                                  user_abc
CosttoServe599a8e8421a80              25
runningTotal                          100
Maintenance599a8e8421a80              5
BusinessEnhancements599a8e8421a80     25
BusinessEnhancements599a8e8421a94     25
Maintenance599a8e8421a94              10
FrontierInvestments599a8e8421a94      5
CosttoServe599a8e8421a86              0
FrontierInvestments599a8e8421a86      5
```

I'm attempting to delete all keys that contain:

```
599a8e8421a94
```

Is there any way to do a like/wild card type delete on session storage?

Comment: Title is a bit misleading session storage `!=` local storage.

Comment: Thanks @Script47 I am not attempting to insinuate this...I will rename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the `sessionStorage` object and check if a key contains `599a8e8421a94`, if it does, remove it:

```
for (var key in sessionStorage) {
    if (key.indexOf('599a8e8421a94') !== -1)
        sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

An example of it in action:

```
/**  Define dummy data... **/
var obj = {
    'no-clean': 'i will not be cleaned.',
    'testing599a8e8421a94': 25,
    'another_test599a8e8421a94': 'e,ndleknfew',
    '599a8e8421a94somemoretesting': '2knmsdkgsdg'
};

/** Loop through our dummy data and add it to sessionStorage. **/
for (var key in obj) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, obj[key]);
}

/** This is the part you will need, loop through sessionStorage object. **/
for (var key in sessionStorage) {
    /** Check if the key contains the search string... **/
    if (key.indexOf('599a8e8421a94') !== -1)
        sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
}

console.log(sessionStorage)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Ln6j7vx/) - Open the console to see the remaining key/value in the `sessionStorage` object.

**Reading Material**

[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Script47! Testing now will accept answer asap!